# gráficos básicos en R

Tags: r

Ya se que la libreria ggplot2 es la más usada para hacr gráficos en R pero si solo quieres hacer algo muy básico como por ejemplo dado este data frame donde tengo por cada año el coste de cada proyecto
[image: df]

Si solo necesito una gráfica por ejemplo donde se muestre por cada año (ejex) ese coste (eje y) hay alguna opcion mas sencilla que meterse en ggplot?

Un saludo

Comment: ¿Que tipo de gráfico? ¿Podrías compartir una muestra de los datos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes extraer los años del df de los nombres de la columnas convertidos a números con `as.numeric()` y recorrer las filas del df. 
 Puedes usar la función `plot(x, y, ....)` o `barplot()`. Acepta múltiples argumentos para formatear los gráficos, pueden ser útiles en tu caso los límites del eje y `ylim`, la etiqueta del eje x `xlab="Años"`, la del eje y `ylab="Coste"` y la del título `main="df$Nombre[i]"` para el título de la fila i-ésima .Puedes ver también la función `par()`. En el help hay ejemplos, pero algo básico para la primera fila sería como:

```
i <- 1
plot(
   2007:2020,
   df[i, 3:16],
   xlab="Años",
   ylab="Coste",
   type="b",
   ylim = c(0, max(df[i, 3:16])),
   main = df$Nombre[i]
)
grid() # dibuja una grilla opcionalmente
```

Si quieres recorrer el df entero encierra el plot (sin el `i <- 1`) en 
 `for (i in 1:nrow(df)) { plot(....) }`